# The probability of getting exactly one error-free submission in a day

Tags: probability

A lecturer has an apparently unending stream of manuscripts to mark. These appear in his pigeonhole at random times, at an average rate of 10 per day. On average 10% of the manuscripts are free of errors (wishful thinking!). What is the probability that the lecturer will see exactly one error-free manuscript
(a) after he has marked 10 of them? [Hint: 10 trials, each with two possible outcomes, resulting in 9 failures...]
(b) after a day? [Hint: what is the mean number of perfect manuscripts arriving per day? What then is the probability of exactly one appearing?]

My solutions: for a) I did : $1 - (0.9)^{10}= 0.651$ for b) same because since 10 are arriving in 1 day so same calculation right?

If it's wrong please show me the correct way? Thanks

Comment: When your title "Probability question" is not accepted because of how vague it is, replacing it with "Probability quest" is __not__ what you are expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints.**

a) The probability that exactly $k$ of $n$ trials are successful, when trials are independent and successful with probability $p$, is given by the binomial expression

$$
\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$

b) The probability that exactly $k$ trials are successful, when trials arrive according to a Poisson process with mean $\lambda$ and are independent and successful with probability $p$, is given by the Poisson expression

$$
\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda p}
$$